# Swing: Getting a component's parent from another class

Tags: java, swing, components, parent-child

I have a main class, where all my gui components are made called Math.java. In a separate class (Calc), I get all of the components and save them in local components from Math in the constructor of Calc. The only thing that doesn't work is when I try to get the parent component of one of the components, it always returns null. When I directly access the JLabels in Math, it works.

cards[] is an array of JLabels. panel2a and layer are JPanels.

```
 public void clear()
{
    for(int i =0;i <cards.length; i++)
    {
//this works, calling the components directly
        if(math.cards[i].getParent().equals(math.panel2a) )
        {
            math.panel2a.remove(cards[i]);

            layer.add(cards[i]);

            layer.repaint();
        }
//this doesn't work, using the local components
        if(cards[i].getParent().equals(panel2a) )
        {
            panel2a.remove(cards[i]);

            layer.add(cards[i]);

            layer.repaint();
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: " I get all of the components and save them in local components from Math in the constructor of Calc." show this

Comment: @rasen58 show us some code. Most likely, you are accessing different instances of those components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two arrays do in fact hold references to the same object, then there is no way (that I know of) for any of that object's methods to behave differently depending on where the object reference is stored. In other words, if it's the same object, then `math.cards[i] == cards[i]` and there is absolutely no way that you'll get different results depending on whether you call `math.cards[i].anyMethod()` or `cards[i].anyMethod()`.

Since you are seeing different results, the arrays must not have the same objects. You probably haven't added the contents of the local `cards` array to any container. Also keep in mind that when you add a component to one container, that component automatically gets removed from any container it might already be in.